# SMS gateway for (legally) spoofing SMS messages

Tags: web-services, mobile, sms, sms-gateway

I'm looking for an SMS gateway to send text messages over an HTTP interface.

However, some SMS gateways do not allow to set the sender ID, and those who allow it either require the user to prove that the sender ID is his own mobile phone number, or they manually check each sender ID to prevent [SMS Spoofing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMS_spoofing).

For my application, however, I need to be able to set the sender ID as part of the HTTP request. Depending on the number of users, I might have thousands of different sender IDs, and I cannot authenticate or review them separately.

The purpose of my application is completely legal, as is the reason why I need to be able to send spoofed text messages.

**Edit:**

It seems that bulksms.com does allow what I need as soon as they trust the user to some extent. If you know of other gateways which allow setting the sender ID dynamically, please let me know.

Comment: You need to let us know where you are located. There are different Gateways in different countries

Comment: Thanks, I'm located in Switzerland, but my app should work in as many countries as possible. The more countries the better. If I need different gateways for different countries, then so be it, but I'd prefer a gateway which covers at least most of the developed countries. There are gateways which cover most countries, for example bulksms.com, but they do not allow setting the sender ID.

Comment: You legally own thousands of sender numbers/IDs? You've got to admit... it sounds sketchy.

Comment: I don't. But every user of my app owns about one.

Comment: This isn't allowed in the US and some countries charge a fee for this: http://www.quora.com/How-can-I-send-an-SMS-via-web-originating-from-my-phone-number-and-not-third-party-app-number

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to respect that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally settled with [Routo Messaging](http://www.routomessaging.com), and the experience so far is very promising. They let you set the sender ID as soon as you have made your first payment, and if you describe them the reason you need it, they let you set the sender ID even on the free test messages you get when signing up on their website.

Disclaimer: I am not affiliated with Routo.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like the gateway you suggsted does let you set the sender ID. From their FAQ :

> 1. Is it possible to use the "sender id" parameter?
>
> Setting of the Sender ID can be enabled after your initial credits
>   purchase. Sender Id requests are processed manually and thus we
>   suggest you request a sender Id change within office hours for a swift
>   response. Giving you full control of your sender ID, is only available
>   after you have been a regular and trusted user. Sender Id can also be
>   set via http request and email to SMS.

Comment: I think the OP wants to set it dynamically (programmatically), not assign it once (bureaucratically) --- which is the [way I read the FAQ](http://www.bulksms.com/int/w/faq.htm#senderid).

Comment: You're right, I need to set it dynamically, which was prohibited by the gateway when I signed up there and bought some initial credits. But I did not notice the part of the FAQ where they're saying that they give me full control of the sender ID as soon as they sort of 'trust' me. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

[Fogmo](http://fogmo.com) offer an API for this very purpose.

Comment: the links dead now