# How can I send an SMS via php, originating from my phone number and not a third party app/number?

Tags: php, sms

I would like to know how I can send a text message (sms) from a web using php and have its origin as my number. Basically, a web messaging procedure for my number instead of the messages being sent from a number assigned by a third party.

Comment: If your number is Android-based, you might be able to do this via Google's new messages.android.com, but I doubt it.

Comment: Find an SMS Gateway that you like and implement their API.

Comment: @PatrickQ You're missing the requirement of "and have its origin as my number"...

Comment: @AlexHowansky I'm pretty sure many gateways will allow you to specify the sender the message appears to be from.

Comment: @PatrickQ Hmm, I've only used Twilio, which allows setting the sender only if it's one of their own numbers. <shrug> Dunno, I've reached the extent of my knowledge on the subject.

Answer (score 2):

You need to research a suitable service provider who can offer you this at a low cost. More than one of those exist. So when you have the choice, you could compare how good their api is. Then you program in php the client for their api. Often they have some sample code available in various programming languages. I would also think about using a message queue. Because if their service is interrupted, you only want your sms function to stop and not your entire site (which can happen if your code waits for their answer ad infinitum).

tl;dr: There is no simple way to program it in php. I outlined one possible way above.

*edit* You could have a look at the discussion here: [SMS gateway for (legally) spoofing SMS messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8705081/sms-gateway-for-legally-spoofing-sms-messages)

Comment: Note that OP has a requirement of "and have its origin as my number." This won't be met in the scenario you describe.

Comment: There are service providers who offer setting a custom sender ID when you are a trusted customer and prove that you own that number, for example. But researching this is beyond the scope of a stackoverflow answer, I guess. I edited my original answer.

Comment: Hrmm looks like all the links on that answer are dead, poking around for some more details...

Comment: OK looks like [BulkSMS](http://bulksms.com) is the only site referenced there that's still live, and they do advertise "Custom Sender ID".

Comment: Note that messages sent with a custom Sender ID can not be replied to, if that is a concern.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that many SMS APIs allow you to arbitrarily set the Sender ID, but note that Sender ID is *not* the same as the originating phone number, and that setting the Sender ID prevents replies. If you want the message to actually come from your device, and be reply-able, you can use [smsgateway.me](https://smsgateway.me/).

You install an app on your device, use PHP to send a request to the API, the API host pushes that request to the app running on your device, and then the app sends the SMS directly from your device.

Pro:

- The SMS *literally* comes from your device.
- Replies to your messages will come back to your device.

Con:

- You must have the app installed.
- You must have your device running at all times.